# Generate automatic value and data when there are some value in a column in Google Sheets with GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

In my spreadsheet I would generate automatically, when in col B there are these values:

- yellow
- green
- black
- brown

In col F the value "SI" and in col J the timestamp of the operation in col B.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_oPC01vUjLYlCikyuk35bERa2Bughm_xDJSaim-wD58/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1):

#### Using onEdit to set value of column10 based on edit and value of B and value of F

```
 function onEdit(e) {
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  //e.source.toast('Entry')
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet1" && e.range.columnStart == 2 ) {
    //e.source.toast('Flag1')
    const cA = ['yellow','green','black','brown'];
    if(~cA.indexOf(e.value) && e.range.offset(0,4).getValue() == "SI") {
      //e.source.toast('Flag2')
      let ts = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"dd/MM/yyyy")
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,10).setValue(ts);
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: I have this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
https://ibb.co/BfyNr5x

Comment: I'd guess that you tried to run it from the script editor without supplying the event object. That's a common error amongst new users. In runs off of the onedit trigger so you will have to insert your sheet name and then edit that sheet to check it's performance.

Comment: I have inserted my sheet name "Sheet1" instead "Your sheet name" but your script not works.

Comment: Try it now.....

Comment: I have the same error...

Comment: I tested it and it works for me so I have to ask how you are running the function.  Like I said you cannot run it from the script editor.  It requires the onedit trigger.